# visualsvn assembly reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, webforms, visualsvn, assembly-references

I'm using visualsvn with Visual Studio 2012 to share a webforms project between myself and two partners. When one of us makes a project and somebody else tries to open it, we get many assembly reference errors:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4992384/error%20screen%20cap.JPG]

This makes me think that when the solution is uploaded, it is missing files. All users are using VS2012.

Anyone know what would cause these errors?

Comment: Have you made certain that the assemblies listed above are in fact installed on the other computer?

Comment: Yes - the computer that creates the project can always run it just fine.

Comment: how do you upload the project to Visual SVN Server? And how ddo you check it out onto another machine?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the version of .Net Framework your using is the same as the dlls? Looks like they are different. (check its not on client profile)

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but all users are on .NET Framework 4.5, and it always runs fine on the machine that creates the project.